# Cannot convert value of type() to closure result type NSDictionary in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

I have to return a value of this function.I am getting error in this line

```
func GetStation(url : String, completionHandler: (stationDictionary: NSDictionary) -> ()) {
    getResonse(url, completionhandler: { (dict) -> NSDictionary in
       completionHandler(stationDictionary: dict) // Error on this line 
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you please print the response you are getting?

Comment: My code is not execute they show error

Comment: completionHandler(stationDictionary: dict) as? NSDictionary  when i use this line code execute get response but crash on this line

Comment: Try With `completionHandler(stationDictionary: dict as? NSDictionary)`

Comment: Can you reveal URL? Also are you using any framework?

Comment: getResonse(url) { (dict) -> NSDictionary in
            

            completionHandler(stationDictionary: dict)
            return dict

Answer (score 3):

**This will surely work.**

```
func GetStation(url : String, completionHandler: (stationDictionary: NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary) {
    getResonse(url, completionhandler: { (dict) -> NSDictionary in
       completionHandler(stationDictionary: dict) // Error on this line 
    })
}
```

**and use it like,**

```
var dict = NSDictionary()
temp.GetStation("your url") { (stationDictionary) -> NSDictionary in
    dict = stationDictionary;
    print("your dictionary := \(stationDictionary)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func GetStation(url : String, completionHandler: (stationDictionary: NSDictionary) -> ()) {
    getResonse(url) { (dict) -> NSDictionary in
        completionHandler(stationDictionary: dict)
        return dict
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actully you might wrong code for getResonse...
It should be like below..

```
func getResonse(url : String, completionHandler: (dictionary:NSDictionary) -> Void) {
}
```

So you should call  GetStation like below...

```
func GetStation(url : String, completionHandler: (stationDictionary: NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary) {
    getResonse(url) { (dictionary) -> Void in
        return completionHandler(stationDictionary: dictionary)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi..Is this answer works?It should.Because I have tested in xcode.